# If I enter just zeros then textbox is left empty

Tags: javascript, function, input, textbox

I have a textbox where user enters in the total weight of an assignment. Now if the user enters 0004, then it will display 4 which is fine, if user enters 002, then it displays 2, but if the user enters 0000, then it will display 0000. I want it to display 0 but I don't know how to do it. If I do textbox.value >= 0, then if I enter in 0000 then it removes all 0's and the text box is left empty. How is it suppose to be coded so that it removes all but one 0 if user just enters in zeros?

Coding is below:

```
if (textbox.value > 0) {
            var textboxstring = textbox.value.replace(/^0*/, '');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var textboxstring = parseInt(textbox.value,10)
```

will do the trick. You need the additional **10** argument to so that string is interpreted as decimal number and not octal

Comment: radix argument tells parseInt what base the string is to be interpreted in. base 10 , hexadecimal etc. Ten in base 10 is 10 but in hexadecimal is "A" and octal is "12"

Comment: i will test it give me 2 minutes

Comment: The ??? was because I didn't understand what radix is, seems confusing, but it did not work after specifying 10, sorry

Comment: @Malcolm: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: @mu I can see what you mean when if you don't include a radix, 010 does actually output 8 lol

Comment: If what you have already works for everything else... do a `textboxstring = textboxstring + 0` at the end and it will work for the **000*** case as well

Comment: it still didn't work sorry, it still displays 000... If it is 009 or 00004 or 0007 etc then it is fine at they display 9, 4 and 7, that has always been fine but it is just 00000 or 000 or 00000000 that does not display just simply 0. This is difficult

Comment: I think your problem might be `textboxvalue  > 0` check which will fail when value is `0000`

Comment: If I do Number(...) then 009 is 9 and 00003 is 3 but 00000 is 00000, if I do parseInt then 009 is 0 and 00003 is 0 but 00000 is 00000

Comment: ur right parapura, I used Number instead of parseInt but whne I changed >= 0, it worked great. I did try this before but this was when I was using replace(...), but when using Number(0, it worked. Thank you parapura :) and thanks to everybody else

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that:

```
textbox.value = Number(textbox.value);
```

should do the job (or any of the many ways to convert a string to a number).

Comment: I changed it to Number(textbox.value) and even it is better than the replace code I have done, it does not help convert 00000 to 0.

Comment: I rated parapura as best answer because he helped me through comments, but your answer was a huge help. Thank You :)

Comment: Using: `<input onblur="this.value = Number(this.value);">`, entering "00000" is changed to "0" on blur. Anyway, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are all of your values expected to be integral?

If so, consider using [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). If you may expect answers with a fractional part, use [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
if (textbox.value > 0) {
   var textboxstring = textbox.value.replace(/^0*/, '');
else
   var textboxstring = textbox.value.replace(/^[0]+/g,'0');
```